# Looking for a way to alphabetize the display of a table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, indexing

I've got two models, Character and Skills. I'm looking for a way to automatically sort all skills by skill.name in the view.

Here's some code from my view:

```
<h2><%= @character.name %>'s Skills</h2>

<% @character.skills.reject {|skill| skill.new_record? }.each do |skill| %>
<b><%= skill.name %></b><br /><br />
...
<%= skill.ranks %><br />
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_character_skill_path(@character, skill) %>  
<br /><br />
<% end %>
```

And here's the code from my controller:

```
def index
@character = Character.find(params[:character_id])
@skill = @character.skills.build
@skills = @character.skills.find(:all, :order => 'name')
end
```

I'm not sure the last bit will actually work, and I'm not sure how to call it in the view if it DOES work. Any input? Also, this will alphabetize new instances of skill, right? As in, I have skill A and skill D, then add skill B, it will display as A, B, D? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the array of skills, and just do `.sort`

So, if you had a character, where `@character.skills` was:

```
@character.skills
=> ["Archery", "Magic", "Sneak", "Combat", "Healing", "Repair", "Fishing"]
```

You could do:

```
@sorted_skills = @character.skills.sort
=> ["Archery", "Combat", "Fishing", "Healing", "Magic", "Repair", "Sneak"]
```

Doing this sets `sorted_skills` to the naturally ordered array of skills, but does NOT alter the original order of `@character.skills`. However, if you instead called `@character.skills.sort!` (note the `!`), it WOULD sort, and permanently change the order of the array in @character.skills (at least until that variable goes out of scope). `.sort!` does not alter the model, or data in the database in any way.

You can also `.sort` any array, say of integers, and Ruby will sort them in an intelligent way. There's even more to it than that, but it sounds like this should cover your needs.

[Ruby documentation for Array class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html)

Comment: This helps, but users can create any skill they like, so how would I create an array without a predetermined list of skills?

Comment: I thought that's what your line, `@skills = @character.skills.find(:all)` was doing. If it's in your database, when you're retrieving it via `.find`, it should give you an array of objects. Am I missing part of your question?

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense. But I'm still unclear how to call this array in the view. Would it be something like <% @character.sorted_skills %> ? And do I need to populate the array manually, as in ["Archery", "Magic" ] and so on, or is that populated automatically with the .find(:all) method?

Comment: (1) if the variable is built in the controller, and starts with an `@` symbol (as in the case of `@sorted_skills`), it will be available in the view automatically as `@sorted_skills`, just as you have guessed. (2) Yes, the `.find(...)` method returns an array containing the values that it finds.